# I get an error in SQL Server from the subquery that works in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee
WHERE (Salary,Department) IN (SELECT MAX(salary), department 
                              FROM Employee
                              GROUP BY Department)
```

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 78
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Comment: You can't just dump some PostgreSQL into a different RDBMS and expect it to "just work". You need to translate the SQL to the appropriate dialect. `IN` works with scalar values, not tuplues, in T-SQL.

Comment: Always read the manual & an introduction re syntax & functionality you want to use. PS [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [mre]

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server, like some other RDBMS does not accept ROW VALUE CONSTRUCTOR everywhere in queries because it is a fine mess for the optimizer to reach a optimized execution plan...

So a syntaxe like :

```
(ColA, Colb, ...) = (Col1, Col2, ...)
```

That result from your WHERE clause and the subquery SELECT clause is not accepted.

The equivalent is to use an EXISTS universal quantifier that is much more efficient...

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Employee AS E
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1/0
              FROM Employee AS S
              WHERE S.department = E.Department
              GROUP BY Department
              HAVING MAX(S.salary) = E.Salary)
```

This syntax to avoid on PG is one of the reasons that PostGreSQL perform much less than MS SQL Server !